# Page content to a string - Android

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest, androidhttpclient

I have the following php page that returns 1 or 0: http://klh-dev.com/lehava/lehava/system/isloggedin.php
I'm trying to create a public String that returnes this page content (which is 0 or 1).
I tried several times few different things but I got errors.

I tried this:

```
    public String IsLoggedIn() {
        String url_text = "http://klh-dev.com/lehava/lehava/system/isloggedin.php";
        String response_str = null;
        try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url_text.toString());
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                response_str = client.execute(request, responseHandler);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("There is an error");
        }
        return response_str;
}
```

I have tried few other things but always same thing happend.

Errors:

```
11-01 08:27:07.677: I/System.out(24314): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-01 08:27:07.677: W/System.err(24314): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-01 08:27:07.677: W/System.err(24314):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:653)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at com.klh.lehava.MainActivity.IsLoggedIn(MainActivity.java:378)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at com.klh.lehava.MainActivity.selectItem(MainActivity.java:221)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at com.klh.lehava.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:170)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at com.klh.lehava.MainActivity$DrawerItemClickListener.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:166)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1114)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2912)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3646)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5144)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
11-01 08:27:07.688: W/System.err(24314):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
11-01 08:27:07.698: W/System.err(24314):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you,
Morha13

Comment: Debug it and see the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged. See the document Designing for Responsiveness.
you need add a thread

new Thread(new Runnable() {

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get=new HttpGet("http://klh-dev.com/lehava/lehava/system/isloggedin.php");
             ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String response_str = null;
            try {
                response_str=client.execute(get,responseHandler);
                System.out.println(response_str);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working, I got the number to the logs. Now how can I get the response_str outside of the Thread?

Comment: @user3825694 set a global variable

Comment: Is it possible to make a WebView and this httpclient run on the same session?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `logcat`, it seems the problem lies because you try to do the connection on the main UI thread. You better use `AsyncTask` or `Thread` and do the operation in `onBackground` or `run`, respectively.

Also, dont forget to add the internet `permission`.

There is a workaround which i dont recommended :

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Using those 2 code in your `onCreate` should solve your error. But still, its discouraged to do the connection on the UI thread because it will make the UI lag or even unresponsive. You **must** do the connection on the **separate** (background) thread for the best result.

Look at this for more information about AsyncTask (with example too) : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Ok I will try it, thank you, I do have the interent connection permission and its working.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work.. but the other answer did. Do you know if its possible to make a webview and httpclient use the same cookies? Because the value that the page returns is being set by a cookie, and the httpclient don't use the same cookies as the webview

Comment: @user3825694 The other answer, in fact is my answer + he babysit you with code :). Please create another question for that